# Issue integrating the Open Graph meta tag

Tags: php, html, facebook, twitter, facebook-opengraph

I am trying to integrate the Open Graph and Twitter Card on my site. Everything works fine until I add the meta tag:

```
<meta property="og:image" itemprop="image primaryImageOfPage" name="twitter:image" content="my-site-name.com/resources/images/logo.png" />
```

At this stage, I get the **headers already sent** error.

However, if I trim down the length of the image url, say to `logo.png`, the error disappears.

Is there something I am doing wrong? Is there a maximum length value to the **content** attribute of meta tags?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing this

```
content="my-site-name.com/resources/images/logo.png"
```

To this:

```
content="http://my-site-name.com/resources/images/logo.png"
```